I am requesting or I request Mr David to come on / up to the stage. Which expression is correct in the native context?
While inviting the guests to the stage, In India, it is usually said that now I request Mr David to come on to the stage. Some professors I know say that it should be come up to the stage.
My point is can we say  I am requesting Mr David to come on to or come up to the stage? I hope my doubt will be clarified by the experts on the site

You can say either. It is ridiculous to suggest that only one of those is right. You could say 'mount the stage' or 'grace the stage with his presence' or probably many other things.

Or are you asking about the difference between the present continuous and simple present?

Yes. I am asking two things- one is the tense and the other is the correct verb and the correct preposition that follow it. I want to know all the possible expressions in the context

It would be natural to use come up to if Mr David will have to climb steps to get on to the stage (but on to wouldn't be wrong).

Note: We ask them to do it, we don't request that they do it. Notice the grammar.

It depends on who's doing the asking and what the relationship is. Your examples aren't particularly polite or formal, but would be fine e.g. for a professor addressing a student. If you wanted to be really formal, you'd say something like "Could I please request..." If you're determined to choose between your two options, the simple present sounds more natural. Unless you're addressing someone other than Mr David (either giving a commentary or speaking to his agent/wife/child), when present continuous might be preferred.

Either preposition is fine, but they mean slightly different things.

Please come up to the stage.

Up here has at least two possible meanings. It may imply that the stage is raised above the level of the floor, and the request is to ascend from the floor to the stage. Alternatively the request may be to move closer to the stage area. For example, if someone is at the back of the room, calling them to come up is the same as calling them to come forward. Here up has a metaphoric sense, of moving from a less important to more important place.

Please come on to the stage.

On the stage means "on top of". Being on the stage is the same as being on the dance floor, or being on the sports field. On to or onto suggests a movement resulting in being on. For example:

We were on the dance floor while our favourite song was playing.
We got onto the dance floor when our favourite song began playing.


It seems to me a good answer. I thank Mr peter for his prompt and useful response

Please join me on stage. is really the nicest way to say this.

Most English professors I know say May I request Mr David to come on to the stage though join me on the stage may be nice but rarely used or heard atleast in the Indian context

There is a stage with a presenter. The presenter say:
"Mr. David, will you please join me on the stage?" [the most polite]
Mr. David then came up on the stage.
Not up to. come on stage.
